# How to store the result of each iteration of a cycle? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

I'm making a stored procedure, the purpose is to produce a Forecast for maintenance schedule, it so that when I give it a range  of dates and amount of days, it would give me a set of results displaying the different dates that fall under that criteria.
I have been trying with a while loop, but I have not been able to get more than 1 result, I only get the last possible result of the range.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ApruebaFecha](
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @LastDate   DATETIME,   -- Last Scheduled Date (Range Start)
    @Setting1   INT,        -- Length of Period
    @FechaHasta datetime,   -- End of Range
    @Result     DATETIME    OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN

    /* Today */
    DECLARE
        @TodaysDate     DATETIME
        SELECT  @TodaysDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 101), 101)
        SELECT convert(datetime, CONVERT(varchar,@FechaHasta,101),101 )

    -- Finding today's date after resetting the time to midnight

    /* Schedule Date */
    DECLARE 
            @ScheduleDate   DATETIME

    -- Find the starting schedule date. If the schedule date is in a previous 
    -- month, adjust to the current month

    -- Adjust the days
        SELECT  @ScheduleDate   =   @LastDate
        WHILE   (@ScheduleDate  <   @TodaysDate AND @TodaysDate <@FechaHasta)
            SELECT  @ScheduleDate   =   DATEADD(day,    @Setting1,  @ScheduleDate)

        IF  (@ScheduleDate  =   @LastDate)
            SELECT  @ScheduleDate   =   DATEADD(day,    @Setting1,  @ScheduleDate)
            SELECT  @Result = @ScheduleDate

            WHILE(@Result <@FechaHasta)
            BEGIN
                IF(@Result <@FechaHasta)
                    SELECT  @Result =   DATEADD(day,    @Setting1,  @Result)
                    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [00TblFecha] ON 
                    INSERT INTO dbo.[00TblFecha](idFecha,jobno,fecha)VALUES('','',@Result)
                    SET IDENTITY_INSERT[00TblFecha] OFF 

                    print @Result
            end

END -- GetScheduleDate_Daily_PeriodicDay
```

Comment: I don't totally understand what you are trying to do here. Are you just trying to get a listing of dates starting at LastDate? You shouldn't use a loop for this. You should instead use a tally or numbers table.http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: Hola Perla. Can you show us sample data and expected result? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Also if you are using sql server 2012+ you should check for `LEAD` and `LAG`  analytic functions

Comment: Not sure the loop is necessary.  Some sample data would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

the result that you see is from this statement at line 5:
 SELECT convert(datetime, CONVERT(varchar,@FechaHasta,101),101 )

you should put a statement at the end of your stored procedure like this :

```
select idFecha,jobno,fecha 
from dbo.[00TblFecha]
```